# Metafont for Mac in terminal

Tags: mac, metafont

I installed MacTex with Metafont, but when I went to call the program in the terminal by typing mf, I got this error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/TeX/texbin/mf
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

What could I do?

Comment: Welcome! Do you have X11 installed? How exactly did you install MacTeX?

Comment: +1 to @cfr's questions, and you can also try `mf-nowin` if you don't need the X window.

Comment: You can get X11 by following the links [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201341).

Comment: `mf-nowin` worked, but what is its difference with the normal `mf` command?

Comment: I installed X11 and now the normal `mf` command works!

Comment: I installed MacTex the normal way, I think : [here](http://tug.org/mactex/).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting as answer to avoid “closing this question as off-topic because it has been answered in the comments”…)*

- You can use `mf-nowin` instead of `mf`, if you don't need the graphics.
- You can install X11 from https://www.xquartz.org/